# Calling Jquery function from link onClick attribute

Tags: 7, javascript

I'm trying to call a jQuery function from a link's onClick attribute but I get the following error: Uncaught TypeError: Drupal.behaviors.main.test is not a function.

I created a simple module that will create a block displaying a list of events. The block template will output the following HTML code:

```
<ul id="events">
    <li><a href="#" onclick="Drupal.behaviors.main.test(1)">Event1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="Drupal.behaviors.main.test(2)">Event2</a></li>
</ul>
```

Each link has a onClick attribute calling Drupal.behaviors.main.test($id).

On my theme's info file, I include a test.js file with the following code:

```
(function ($) {
    Drupal.behaviors.main = {

        attach: function(context, settings) {

            $(function test() {
                console.log('yo')
            });


            $('#home').slick({
             //init slick
            });

       }
    }
})(jQuery);
```

When the document is ready, slick plugin is well initialized and test() is called so I get 'yo' on the console. It's when I click the links that I get the error, so I'm thinking about a scope problem since the function is called from a module but is defined on my theme.
Does anyone have any idea?

Thanks in advance!

--EDIT--
Thank to rémy, I managed to resolve my issue, here's what I did:
My block outputs the following HTML:

```
<ul id="events">
    <li>
        <a href="#" id="1" class="whatever">Event1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" id="2" class="whatever">Event2</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And on my test.js file:

```
(function ($) {
    Drupal.behaviors.main = {

        attach: function(context, settings) {

            $('.whatever').click(function() {
              console.log(this.id);
            });

            $('#home').slick({
             //init slick
            });

       }
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use an id on your anchors, no onclick:

```
<li><a href="#" id="whatever">Event2</a></li>
```

then use the click event on it in the behavoir:

```
(function ($) {
    Drupal.behaviors.someClicks = {
        attach: function(context, settings) {
            $('#whatever').click(function() {
               console.log('vamoooh');
            });
       }
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Thank you rémy! Edited my question with working corrections!